# Can I run tests using "solana-program-test" on devnet?

Tags: rust, tests

The test here uses "solana-program-test" and async/await.
https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/master/src/program-rust/tests/lib.rs

Can I run these test scripts on devnet by modifying some parameters?

I am wondering if I can use this async/await type test code to interact with actual deployed programs on devnet.

Comment: you've edited this question to mean something totally different than what it did orignally

Answer (score 1):

You'll have far better control over your test environment if you instead use the [`solana-program-test`](https://docs.rs/solana-program-test/1.11.3/solana_program_test/) crate or `solana-test-valdidator` binary from the [CLI tools](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools)

Comment: The test uses solana-programa-test.

the line
`let (mut banks_client, payer, recent_blockhash) = program_test.start().await;`
connects to the local network, I suppose.

Can I make the devnet client?

Comment: no. `ProgramTest` uses a very stripped down version of the runtime, not a full local-cluster.  if you want to use devnet, you'd need to adapt your tests.  however, as I alluded to in my answer, you don't really want to use devnet to back your test framework.  use something that you have full control over, like the things my answer suggests

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't run this test without modifications.
As mentioned in comments to [previous](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/520/285) answer, solana-program-test is not a full validator. It runs only bpf/sbf interpreter with access to accounts, created in the test.

If you want to adapt the test to devnet, you have to rewrite it with `solana-client` crate and manually send all the needed instructions including program deployment, account creation, filling the accounts with necessary data, if needed. However, you can't write to accounts not owned by you and before changing the ownership runtime zeroize any data, stored in the account, so it is only possible to "prepare" account owned by "user",  not the program itself.

To sum up, you'd better stick with `solana-program-test`.

If you really want to run tests on devnet, you can take a look on the [utility](https://github.com/solcery/on-chain/tree/dev/db-program/db-cli) we used to prepare the environment for out program (it has quite nontrivial bootstrap process exactly because of a number of program-owned accounts, that have to be present on-chain).
Sorry in advance for the absence of comments in this crate, right now we are working on a different part of the project.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. You just have to use devnet for deploying the contracts and also running the tests. This can vary depending on what environment / framework / setup you're using. But in general yes.

Comment: No, you can't do it without heavy modifications of the tests.